# SQLite - how to get rid of annoying trace messages - "Native library pre-loader failed to get setting ... value"?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-server-2008

I developed some C# assembly with UDF for SQL Server 2008.
In particular I have some functions which use SQLite database.
I added there trace listener to write a log file to see what is happing inside.
But there is a problem - on every call to UDF function it is flooding log file with messages like these:

```
20160226,191636.67 [P5816]/[T4]  Native library pre-loader failed to get setting "No_PreLoadSQLite" value: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetXmlConfigFileName()
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSettingValue(String name, String default)
```

I can see that on every call it is logging ~18 of such messages for every of following parameters:

```
"No_PreLoadSQLite", "PreLoadSQLite_NoSearchForDirectory",  "PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture",
"PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture", "PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory",   "PreLoadSQLite_UseAssemblyDirectory",
"PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture", "No_PreLoadSQLite", "PreLoadSQLite_NoSearchForDirectory",
"PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture", "PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture", "PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory",
"PreLoadSQLite_UseAssemblyDirectory", "PreLoadSQLite_ProcessorArchitecture", "No_SQLiteConnectionNewParser",
"DefaultFlags_SQLiteConnection", "No_SQLiteFunctions", "SQLite_ForceLogPrepare"
```

It is a bit annoying to see all the messages in log, difficult to track log messages which related to functionality which I'm interested in.

Could you please advice - how could I get rid of that *extra*/*unwanted* trace messages?

Maybe I need to do some special SQLlite API call to disable loading of all that settings?

Note: to make my UDF assembly working under from SQL Server CLR engine I copied *SQLite.Interop.dll*, *System.Data.SQLite.dll* and *System.Data.SQLite.dll.config* files into C:\Windows\system32. 
As you can see *System.Data.SQLite.dll.config* file is in the same dir as *System.Data.SQLite.dll* but it does not help.

Note: both DLLs *SQLite.Interop.dll*, *System.Data.SQLite.dll* has version 1.0.99.0.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, though I was using [Fody/Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to embed the System.Data.SQLite libraries in my assembly (it's unclear if you're doing something similar).

The error you show comes from [this code](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/c07391185b9267e7):

```
private static string GetXmlConfigFileName()
{
    string directory;
    string fileName;

#if !PLATFORM_COMPACTFRAMEWORK
    directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    fileName = Path.Combine(directory, XmlConfigFileName);

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        return fileName;
#endif

    directory = GetAssemblyDirectory();
    fileName = Path.Combine(directory, XmlConfigFileName);

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        return fileName;

    return null;
}
```

The method `GetAssemblyDirectory` returns `null` if it cannot figure out the path of the assembly, which will make `Path.Combine` throw.  In my case, because Costura loads its assemblies from a stream, they have no directory so `GetAssemblyDirectory` fails.

The good news is that I [opened a ticket with System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/da685c0bacca97c43bde3f00c7f03d3b4ecf1ac5) and it was fixed almost immediately.  Hopefully it will be pushed out soon.